TeX Support For Chinese Language@SE
How about some, simple, TeX support for CL@SE?
Even something such as support for ^n would suite very nicely for pinyin annotated with tones.
Here's something I was playing around with on another SE site:

We have no need for mathrm, at all, I just think it displays text nicely sometimes.
Support for superscripted numbers would be nice though.

Superscripts can be achieved by the <sup> tag. Your example can be typesetted using simple HTML:
ni<sup>3</sup> hao<sup>3</sup>
da<sup>4</sup> ming<sup>2</sup>

which comes out like this:

ni3 hao3
  da4 ming2

I don't see any reason to add TeX support to a language site like CL@SE. TeX is mostly about typing math symbols, and simple math symbols can be typed using HTML codes.
